# BPP being equal to #P under Oracle

Tags: computational-complexity, np

Luca Trevisan [here](http://lucatrevisan.wordpress.com/2008/02/16/approximate-counting/) gives a randomized polynomial-time approximation algorithm for #3-coloring given an NP oracle.

In a similar vein, I was wondering if there were any results on $BPP^{NP}\stackrel{?}{=}$ #P - i.e. outputting a correct count for a #P problem under the presence of an NP oracle with high probability. 
The ideal result of course would tell whether they were equal or not but since we don't know whether P=#P or P=BPP, we can't prove the above false. So I'm also interested in any results that provide evidence either way or prove the above is true (which I'm guessing it is unlikely to be).

If there are no such results, then is $BPP^{NP}$ generally believed to be equal to #P?

**Edit: ** As per Mariano's suggestion, [Here](http://qwiki.stanford.edu/wiki/Complexity_Zoo%3AB#bpp)'s the Complexity Zoo's excellent description of the complexity class BPP. And [here](http://qwiki.stanford.edu/wiki/Complexity_Zoo%3ASymbols#sharpp) is the description of the complexity class #P.

Thanks

Comment: While surely anyone who will be able to answer this will know what BPP is, maybe a very succint description might be of quite some help to us mere humans :P

Comment: Bounded error Probabilistic Polynomial time. See: http://qwiki.stanford.edu/wiki/Complexity_Zoo:B#bpp

Comment: When there are numerous other resources for computer science, are such questions appropriate for MO?

Comment: Theoretical CS is part of mathematics, and there is no MathOverflow for computer science (SO is more applied), so I think the question fits MO well. Also, the Complexity Zoo Veterinarian is Greg Kuperberg.

Comment: @Anweshi: You think computational complexity theory is not appropriate for MO?  Wow.

Comment: Well, I had sorta imagined that since CS guys are so far ahead of mathematics guys in the matter of computer applications and web development, there should be a lot more and much better and focussed resources for CS existing already.

Comment: Every science is part of philosophy. Try posting a question from here in one of the philosophy forums. There is reason why universities run different departments for math and cs sometimes, though cs has a lot in common with math. 

Comment: Yeah, if as Ilya says there is really no stackoverflow site for CS, then it could be posted here. But there really ought to be one. And it is not that Cs guys cannot make one.

Comment: Complexity theory in particular is far closer to mathematics than it is to standard CS stuff like programming, compilers, databases, operating systems, etc. As such it is completely appropriate to have complexity theory questions on MO.

Comment: If I were the one asking the question I would be sorely tempted to post in on stackoverflow saying "People at mathoverflow suggested I ask this question here..." :)

Comment: You know what I meant, there should be a site called csoverflow.net or complexityoverflow.net .. I didn't ask the OP to go and post in stackoverflow. And yes, I also understand the distinction between computational complexity and the rest of computer science. But you have to put an egg in some basket. You cannot break it in two and put in two baskets.

Comment: I do not see any reason why there should be a separate "overflow" for complexity theory and allied branches of CS, any more than there should be a separate one for combinatorics. (Indeed, combinatorics and complexity theory have much more common ground than either has with e.g. algebraic topology.) --- Where does one make the cut? As a rough approximation, I would say that MathOverflow should accomodate questions from any field whose pactitioners spend most of their time writing Lemmata in LaTeX.

Comment: @Anweshi: with due respect, your proposition that CS theory is 'really' part of the same 'egg' as information retrieval and network protocols --- or that CS theorists are substantially more likely than number theorists to know how to set up a website such as MO --- seems to me to indicate that you aren't strongly familiar with either the theoretical or the practical parts of CS. One may as well conflate physicists with mechanical engineers. We simply have divergent priorities, and a different knowledge-base, from your typical programmer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, let's be slightly pedantic and not make statements like P = #P, which cannot possibly be true just because P is a set of decision problems and #P is not. To get a decision version of #P, one can use PP, or something like P<sup>#P</sup>.

About your question, BPP<sup>NP</sup> is contained in P<sup>PP</sup> and P<sup>#P</sup> by Toda's theorem. On the other hand, if P<sup>#P</sup> were contained in BPP<sup>NP</sup>, it would imply that PH is contained in BPP<sup>NP</sup>, which would collapse the polynomial hierarchy to the third (or second?) level, which is considered unlikely.

In conclusion, P<sup>#P</sup> is considered to be more powerful than NP, BPP, BPP<sup>NP</sup> and even NP<sup>NP<sup>NP</sup></sup>.